# How to switch index column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need to change the order of the columns index.
I use set_index(['Race','City'])
My DF look like this:

```
Race|City   |smth
WBP |Warsaw | a
PBZ |Warsaw | c
HMP |Warsaw | e
DUR |Warsaw | a
```

I need this DF to look like this:

```
Race|City   |smth
WBP |Warsaw |a
    |Krakow |b
    |Bydgosz|e
    |Gdansk |g
PBZ |Warsaw |b
    |Bialys |d
```

I try to switch place of "race" and "city" but i get this output:

```
City   |Race|smth
Warsaw |WBP | a
Warsaw |PBZ | c
Warsaw |HMP | e
Warsaw |DUR | a
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['Race', 'City']).sort_index()`?

Comment: That was so simple Thanks :D